# regex not show correcrt result for IPv6 match

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, sample

Why the second localized string is not shown correctly in the console in this sample?

```
Found 3 words IPv6
2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:ff00:0042:8329
2001:0db8::   --- wrong output is here
::1
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "ipv4 model 127.0.0.1 "
        "live 2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:ff00:0042:8329 "
        "another 2001:0db8::ff00:0042:8329 "
        "zip form ::1 ";

    std::regex ex_ipv6 ("(([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){7,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,7}:|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,6}:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,5}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,2}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,3}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,3}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,2}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,5}|[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,6})|:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,7}|:)|fe80:(:[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}){0,4}%[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,}|::(ffff(:0{1,4}){0,1}:){0,1}((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9]).){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}:((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9]).){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9]))");
    auto words_ipv6_begin = 
        std::sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), ex_ipv6);
    auto words_ipv6_end = std::sregex_iterator();

    if (std::regex_search(s, ex_ipv6)) 
    {
        std::cout << "Found "
                  << std::distance(words_ipv6_begin, words_ipv6_end)
                  << " words IPv6\n";

        for (;words_ipv6_begin != words_ipv6_end; words_ipv6_begin++)
        {
            std::cout <<  (*words_ipv6_begin).str() << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you put what is the string not showing correctly and what is the generated output?

Comment: Your regex is 657 characters long. You expect someone to decipher that for you?

Comment: The error is not in regex expression but in print result only.

Comment: Ok. With this regex expression woks: "([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:[0-9A-Fa-f]{0,4}|:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})?|(:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,2})|(:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,3})|(:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,4})|:(:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,5})((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){2}|:(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1[0-9]|[1-9])?[0-9])(\.(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1[0-9]|[1-9])?[0-9])){3})|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){1,6}|:):[0-9A-Fa-f]{0,4}|([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){7}:"

Comment: I'd consider both of those regex solutions unacceptable. Think about the next guy that needs to look at your code and try to understand what it's doing. Even you might have trouble 6 months from now. At the bare minimum, I'd split the string literal onto several lines and add comments on what each part accomplishes.

Comment: `Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions."  Now they have two problems.` ~~ Jamie Zawinski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your prefix check is accepting the string much earlier than it should.  Expression group `([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,7}:` is marking the address prior to the jump as valid, consuming the string, and checking `::ff00:0042:8329` doesn't match any remaining pattern (and would also be considered a separate address if it did).

A couple notes about your regex usage.  `{7,7}` can be simply written as `{7}`.  IPv6 addresses should be `[0-9a-f]` when represented as base16, so you can discard the `[A-F]` checks.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

// RFC5952 outlines canonical formatting for rendering IPv6 addresses as 
// text. Hex values in an address SHOULD be lowercase.  Addresses can be
// shortened ONCE using the symbol '::'.  Whitespace is actually processed
// as part of the pattern, so use \\s to match whitespace.

int main() {
  std::string ipv6 = 
    "(?:"
    // For the first 6 fields, match addresses with no jump (::)...
    "  (?:                                              (?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){6}"
    // ...or a jump.
    "  |                                             :: (?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){5}"
    "  | (?:                         [0-9a-f]{1,4})? :: (?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){4}"
    "  | (?: (?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){0,1} [0-9a-f]{1,4})? :: (?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){3}"
    "  | (?: (?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){0,2} [0-9a-f]{1,4})? :: (?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){2}"
    "  | (?: (?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){0,3} [0-9a-f]{1,4})? :: (?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:)   "
    "  | (?: (?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){0,4} [0-9a-f]{1,4})? ::                      "
    "  )                                                                     "
    // Match the base10/16 addresses with no jump (suffix of above).
    "  (?: [0-9a-f]{1,4} : [0-9a-f]{1,4}                                     "
    "      | (?: (?: 25[0-5] | 2[0-4][0-9] | [01]?[0-9]?[0-9])\\.){3}        "
    "        (?: (?: 25[0-5] | 2[0-4][0-9] | [01]?[0-9]?[0-9]))              "
    "  )                                                                     "
    // Not any above. Check to see if jump is between last 2 fields of addr.
    "  | (?: (?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){0,5} [0-9a-f]{1,4})? :: [0-9a-f]{1,4}        "
    "  | (?: (?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){0,6} [0-9a-f]{1,4})? ::                      "
    ")";
  // End of ipv6 string pattern.

  // Convert readable pattern above into the applicable regex pattern.
  ipv6.erase(std::remove_if(ipv6.begin(), ipv6.end(), ::isspace), ipv6.cend());

  std::regex ipv6_pattern(ipv6);
  const std::string test = "ipv4 model 127.0.0.1 "
                           "live 2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:ff00:0042:8329 "
                           "another 2001:0db8::ff00:0042:8329 "
                           "zip form ::1 ";
  auto result = std::sregex_iterator(test.cbegin(), test.cend(), ipv6_pattern);
  const auto results_end = std::sregex_iterator();

  if (result != results_end) {
    std::cout << "Found "
              << std::distance(result, results_end)
              << " IPv6 address matches.\n";

    while (result != results_end) {
      std::cout << (*result++).str() << '\n';
    }
  }
}
```

Console:

```
Found 3 IPv6 address matches. 
2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:ff00:0042:8329
2001:0db8::ff00:0042:8329
::1
```